# Perform custom function on each row of Dataframe, while ignoring the first col

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to python, still trying to figure out python. I am not sure how to approach this.
I am trying to apply a custom function to calculate the percentile while ignoring the first column as it is a string. and also want to only the last 3 data points of each row.

Tried using the df.rolling function from pandas, but was not successful in its implementation. thanks for the help in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

# df = pd.read_csv('data/imp_vol.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['a',3,None,4,2,4], 
                 "B":['b',2,4,3,2,5], 
                 "C":['c',3,8,5,4,None], 
                 "D":['d',2,None,4,2,None]}) 
df['heading'] = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
new_order = [-1,0,1,2,3]
df = df[df.columns[new_order]]
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
df.update(df.iloc[:, -4:].mask(lambda x: x.isin([0, '0'])).ffill(axis=1))

def perc_func(r):
        x = r
        last_val = x[-1]
        min_val = x.min()
        max_val = x.max()
        percentile = ((last_val - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) * 100)  
        return percentile

df['Percentile'] = df.apply(lambda row:perc_func(row), axis=1)

print(df)
```

sample output which I am after is below (data is only place holder for col percentile):

```
 heading    A    B    C    D  Percentile
0       a  1.0  3.0  2.0  4.0          45
1       b  3.0  2.0  3.0  2.0          44
2       c  0.0  4.0  8.0  8.0          32
3       d  4.0  3.0  5.0  4.0          48
4       e  2.0  2.0  4.0  2.0          59
5       f  4.0  5.0  5.0  5.0          59
```

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: done. given above.

Comment: i'm curious why the column 'A' has 'a' as its first value in `['a',3,None,4,2,4]`? Similarly for the other columns

Comment: if you want to apply to certain columns just select them `df[['cola','colb']].apply(func)`

Comment: my bad - all data in the dataframe would be float or integer. I was trying to put the heading column. where I made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply your custom function on all rows of df, except 1st and also excluding 1st column:

```
In [1157]: df['Percentile'] = df.iloc[1:, 1:].apply(perc_func, 1)                                                                                                                                           

In [1158]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1158]: 
  heading  A  B  C  D  Percentile
0       a  a  b  c  d         NaN
1       b  3  2  3  2         0.0
2       c  0  4  8  8       100.0
3       d  4  3  5  4        50.0
4       e  2  2  4  2         0.0
5       f  4  5  5  5       100.0
```

Comment: @ArunPratimDasgupta Please let me know if the answer helped.